# How to print a line before it is spoke after compilation?

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller, pyttsx

I want to print a line before it is spoke. When I run the program in IDLE, it works fine. But after compilation, the text is spoke first and then printed. Can anyone help me with it?

I tried different ways to type the same code but it didn't work.

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
engine.setProperty('volume', 1)
def say(y):
        print(y, end='')
        engine.say(y)
        engine.runAndWait()
say('Hello World')
```

I want to print a line before it is spoke but it is always spoke first after compilation.

Comment: try adding `flush=True` to your `print` statement.

Comment: First, what do you mean by "compilation", python is a scripting language and it doesn't compile. Second, your print statement is before your playback so, your print statement always works as you desire. Maybe you could put a `sleep` after your `print(y)` would clarify this.

Comment: When you convert your program to executable format, it is called compilation

Answer (score 0):

In some environments, Python's print statement gets "buffered" and not actually printed until there's an idle time.

Try adding

```
import sys
```

and then doing

```
print(y, end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Flushing stdout will force Python to actually display the printed text before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

@JohnAnderson 's comment in the main question did exactly what I wanted.
Adding`flush=True`in print statement did it